# Cypress: Test if element does not exist

Tags: javascript, checkbox, cypress

I want to be able to click on a check box and test that an element is no longer in the DOM in Cypress. Can someone suggest how you do it?

```js
// This is the Test when the checkbox is clicked and the element is there

cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').click();
cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').contains('Some text in this div.')
```

I want to do the opposite of the test above.

So when I click it again the `div` with the class `check-box-sub-text` should not be in the DOM.

Comment: I like cypress because for the most part it is easy and it just works. I get the issue with it only being used in Chrome, but for me I can live with that.

Comment: `cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').contains('Some text in this div.')` in some cases might not work (on some devices). You can replace it with `cy.contains('.check-box-sub-text', 'Some text in this div.')` it will work in same way.

Comment: I think you should clarify the question to "test if element is removed". Otherwise it's confusing with another question, "test if element was never there". The technical implications, and answers, are different depending on the case.

Comment: @alexrogers sometimes you don't need cross browser testing, but just spin up some quick end to end tests. This is specially helpful for small teams that cannot afford testing all the browsers, but barely can support e2e.

Comment: @alexrogers: If you develop Android apps, Chrome is all you need ;-) Adaption to different targets brings more complexity and potential bugs... Also: there should be no need to test if your target is implemented correctly (that's the duty of the developers of said target). You should only need to test your own code ... That's the theory at least ...

Answer (score 535, accepted):

Well this seems to work, so it tells me I have some more to learn about .should()

```
cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').should('not.exist');
```

Comment: HI! I am using pretty much the same code: `cy.get(data-e2e="create-entity-field-relation-contact-name").should('not.exists')` but it fails on `get` and then tries to invoke `should` several times, each of which fails...
any idea what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment, is your selector working on a data attribute? Can you paste your html in the comments? That selector looks odd to me!

Comment: @volk I think `cy.get('[data-e2e="create-entity-field-relation-contact-name"]').should('not.exists')` should work.

Comment: @Maccurt, @YingYang : actually I found the mistake, and it was kind of silly: there is redundant `s` in should: `.should('not.exists')` -> `.should('not.exist')`

Comment: Instead of should() is it possible to wrap above condition in if loop? Thanks

Comment: This works for the case that it is being removed. but in the case that you want it to never exist... https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Existence It will retry until it goes away. This doesn't really work for the title problem which is what most people will be looking for.

Comment: You can also `cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').contains('Some text in this div.').should('not.exist');`   ... so basically just add `.should('not.exist');` to make it the opposite

Answer (score 113):

You can also search for a text which is not supposed to exist:

```js
cy.contains('test_invite_member@gmail.com').should('not.exist')
```

Here you have the result in Cypress: `0 matched elements`

[image]

Reference: [Docs - Assertions, Existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Existence)

Comment: this didn't work for me, the `contains` timed out and caused the test to fail
`CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Im not supposed to be here' but never did.`

Comment: I added more explanations with an example in my answer. After deleting the user `test_invite_member@gmail.com`, Im checking if the email exists somewhere.  the result is `0 element`. What version of Cypress are you using?

Comment: cheers for the update. `npx cypress --version` - 
`Cypress package version: 3.5.0 Cypress binary version: 3.5.0`

Comment: That's working for me now, I'm actually not sure what I missed. Thanks for your help

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Cypress 4. It seems to work for removed element, not element that should not exist at all (eg when testing server side rendering)

Comment: `should('not.exist')` is the other way round to `should('exist')` where `contains` is at the end: `cy.getByData('success_msg').should('exist').contains(address)`

Answer (score 79):

Use `.should('not.exist')` to assert that an element does not exist in the DOM.

---

Do **not** use `not.visible` assertion. It would falsely pass in < 6.0, but properly fail now:

```
// for element that was removed from the DOM
// assertions below pass in < 6.0, but properly fail in 6.0+
.should('not.be.visible')
.should('not.contain', 'Text')
```

Migration Docs here: [Migrating-to-Cypress-6-0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide.html#Migrating-to-Cypress-6-0)

Comment: I will look into this and upgrade to 6

Comment: can we retrieve the boolean flag like true or false

Comment: Which means not.exist/exist checks the presence in DOM? and visible/not visible checks the presence in UI

Comment: should not exist is not working in cypress 8. It fails if cypress did not ever find the element. instead not visible is working.

Comment: @t_dom93 that's a nice answer, i'm facing one issue that i have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546052/trigger-method-in-cypress .  Please could you help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 38):

## Cypress 6.x+ Migration

[According to cypress docs on Existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Existence)

The very popular attempt which is a bit naive will work until it doesn't and then you'll have to rewrite it again... and again...

```
// retry until loading spinner no longer exists
cy.get('#loading').should('not.exist')
```

This doesn't really work for the title problem which is what most people will be looking for.

This works for the case that it is being removed. [but in the case that you want it to never exist...](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Existence) It will retry until it goes away.

However, if you want to test that the element never exists in our case.

> Yes lol. This is what you really want unless you want to just have your headache again another day.

```
// Goes through all the like elements, and says this object doesn't exist ever
cy.get(`img[src]`)
  .then(($imageSection) => {
    $imageSection.map((x, i) => { expect($imageSection[x].getAttribute('src')).to.not.equal(`${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/assets/images/imageName.jpg`) });
})
```

Comment: Agreed, see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7651

Comment: `.map` seems inappropriate if you're ignoring the return value. `.forEach` would be better if you just want to trigger a side effect on each element rather than apply a transformation on each element of the array immutably.

Answer (score 23):

```
cy.get('[data-e2e="create-entity-field-relation-contact-name"]').should('not.exist');
```

might lead to some false results, as some error messages get hidden. It might be better to use

```
.should('not.visible');
```

in that case.

Comment: if it did not exist in the DOM would not.visible work? I will try it out. Thanks!!!!

Comment: For me it was quite the opposite! (`should('not.exist')` fixed a wrong `should('not.be.visible')`)

Comment: if it does not exist in the dom then not.be.visible will work. If you check the cypress logs you will get something like expected undefined to not be visible and the assertion will pass. So in a way not be visible actually covers not exist and not visible in one assertion

Comment: Do not use `should('not.visible')` assertion. It would falsely pass in Cypress < 6.0, but properly fail now for the element that was removed from the DOM. Use `should('not.exist')`. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915773/cypress-test-if-element-does-not-exist/64983253#64983253

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=parent]').should('not.have.descendants', 'img')
```

I check that some `<div data-cy="parent">` has no images inside.
Regarding original question, you can set `data-cy="something, i.e. child"` attribute on inner nodes and use this assertion:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=parent]').should('not.have.descendants', '[data-cy=child]')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `get` and `contains` together to differentiate HTML elements as well.

```
<button type='button'>Text 1</button>
<button type='button'>Text 2</button>
```

Let's say you have 2 buttons with different texts and you want to check if the first button doesn't exist then you can use;

```
cy.get('button').contains('Text 1').should('not.exist')
```

Comment: It works on your case but if button never exist the "get" fails as cypress never found a button into ths DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code

```
expect(opportunitynametext.include("Addon")).to.be.false
```

or

```
should('be.not.be.visible')
```

or

```
should('have.attr','minlength','2')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `should('be.not.be.visible')` be `should('not.be.visible')`?

Answer (score 0):

I closed an element and checked should('not.exist') but the assertion failed as it existed in the DOM. It just that it is not visible anymore.

In such cases, should('not.visible') worked for me. I have just started using cypress. A lot to learn.

Comment: Basically a repeat of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632503/6243352). Consider upvoting it instead of reposting it again.

Answer (score 0):

> No try-catch flow in cypress

In java-selenium, we usually add the NoSuchElementException and do our cases. if UI is not displaying element for some Role based access cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also query for the matched elements inside the body or inside the element's parent container, and then do some assertions on its length:

```
cy.get("body").find(".check-box-sub-text").should("have.length", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, I was having the issue that neither `.should('not.exist')` nor `.should('have.length', 0)` worked - even worse: If the element I was querying was actually there right from the get-go, both asserts still returned true.

In my case this lead to the very strange situation that these three assertions, executed right after each other, were true, even though asserts 1+2 and 3 contradict each other:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="foobar"]').should('not.exist')
cy.get('[data-cy="foobar"]').should('have.length', 0)
cy.get('[data-cy="foobar"]').should('have.text', 'Foobar')
```

After extensive testing, I found out that this was simply a race condition problem. I was waiting on a backend call to finish before running the above 3 lines. Like so:

```
cy.wait('@someBackendCall')
cy.get('[data-cy="foobar"]').should('not.exist')
```

However once the backend called finished Cypress immediately ran the first two assertions and both were still true, because the DOM hadn't yet caught up rerendering based on the backend-data.

I added an explicit wait on an element that I knew was gonna be there in any case, so my code now looks something like this:

```
cy.wait('@someBackendCall')
cy.get('[data-cy="some-element"]').should('contain', 'I am always here after loading')
cy.get('[data-cy="foobar"]').should('not.exist')
```

Comment: You can easily fix with double-command. Start with `.should('exist')` then `.should('not.exist')`. It more precisely says "the element is there, then it is removed".

Comment: In my case the element wasn't there from the get-go

Comment: But - you appear to be saying the opposite in the answer.

Comment: You might be right. I edited the original answer, hopefully making sure that it's for elements that are there from the get-go

Comment: You will probably fix your issue if you upgrade to Cypress 12. There's new functionality that extends the reach of the retry that is conerstone of Cypress testing.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from

```js
cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').should('not.exist');
```

another option is

```js
cy.get('.check-box-sub-text').should(checkBoxSubText => {
  expect(checkBoxSubText).to.not.exist;
});
```

It doesn't add much in this case, but it could be more readable in more complex situations as it splits selecting the object from asserting.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked:

```js
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  if ($body.find("mat-option[aria-selected='true']").length) {
    // Do something if exist
  } else {
    // Do if not exist
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is no element, you can use

```
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').should('not.exist')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This adds nothing to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916050/6243352). Consider simply upvoting that answer.