# How to assert that an alert does not appear?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

When a certain UI bug appears, an alert pops up with an error message. I fixed that bug, and now I want to write a Cypress test.

**How do I write a Cypress test that passes if the alert does not appear?**

I realize that I must [be careful with negative assertions](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/negative-assertions/), so I'll want to make the test as robust as possible.

Related post:
[Cypress: Test if element does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915773/cypress-test-if-element-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How do I write a Cypress test that passes if the alert does not appear?**

1. [Spy](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy#Syntax) on the `window:alert` [event](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events).
2. Wait a few seconds to give the alert time to appear.
3. Use a positive assertion to make sure the spy is what you're expecting.
4. Assert that the spy isn't called.

```
// Typing enter should not produce an alert
let spy = cy.spy(window, 'alert');
cy.get('input[name="MyField"]')
    .type('{enter}')
    .wait(4000)
    .then(() => {
        expect(spy).to.haveOwnProperty('callCount');
        expect(spy).to.not.be.called;
    });
```

5. Also make a positive assertion for whatever is supposed to happen when the bug is fixed.